# Do security providers cause ClassLoader leaks in Java?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, classloader, memory-leaks, jrebel

In my Java EE (Glassfish 3.1.1) application I register a security provider:

```
public static final class XoauthProvider extends Provider {
    public XoauthProvider() {
        super("Google Xoauth Provider", 1.0, "Provides the Xoauth experimental SASL Mechanism");
        put("SaslClientFactory.XOAUTH", "blah.server.utils.XoauthSaslClientFactory");
    }
}

...

XoauthProvider xoauthProvider = new XoauthProvider();
Security.addProvider(xoauthProvider);
```

I have been receiving following exceptions after redeploys:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource [blah.server.utils.XoauthSaslClientFactory], because it has not yet been started, or was already stopped
```

I debugged a little, and it seems that after a redeploy, the server still uses the old classloader when loading this class.

If case I am correct, and it is a ClassLoader leak, what would be an appropriate way to deregister the security provider when the applcation is redeployed/undeployed? Or should I just manually unregister/reregister the provider before calling the method which eventually throws the exception?

By the way, I am using JRebel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does seem that custom `java.security.Provider` registered with `java.security.Security.addProvider()` does cause classloader leaks, unless deregistered with `java.security.Security.removeProvider("providerName")` at application shutdown.

I have created [a project](https://github.com/mjiderhamn/classloader-leak-prevention/) that aims to prevent classloader leaks, which includes a test case that proves this does leak.

You can either make sure to clean up yourself using a `ServletContextListener`, as detailed [here](http://java.jiderhamn.se/2012/01/01/classloader-leaks-ii-find-and-work-around-unwanted-references/#cleanup), or simply use my cleanup component (see [here](http://java.jiderhamn.se/2012/03/04/classloader-leaks-vi-this-means-war-leak-prevention-library/)).

Comment: As per this JDK issue, you should avoid removeProvider and addProvider again: "This leaks memory when Provider instances are continuously, created, used, and de-referenced i":  https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8168469