# sbt using multiple classloaders

Tags: scala, sbt, classloader

Sbt seems to be using different classloaders, making some tests failing when run more than once in an sbt session, with the following error:

```
[info]   java.lang.ClassCastException: net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.EdDSAPublicKey cannot be cast to net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.EdDSAPublicKey
[info]   at com.advancedtelematic.libtuf.crypt.EdcKeyPair$.generate(RsaKeyPair.scala:120)
```

[I tried equivalent code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44822228/pattern-matching-fails-on-second-try) using pattern matching instead of `asInstanceOf` and I get the same result.

How can I make sure sbt uses the same class loader for all test executions in the same session?

Comment: Can you include code that reproduces this issue in your question? Why do you think classloaders are the problem?

Comment: I ended up writing an issue report for sbt to try and debug this, please check https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3306 I wrote a small project reproducing this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's related to this: [Do security providers cause ClassLoader leaks in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420190/do-security-providers-cause-classloader-leaks-in-java). Basically `Security` is re-using providers from old class-loaders. So this could happen in any multi-classpath environment (like OSGi), not just SBT.

Fix for your `build.sbt` (without forking):

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Cleanup(() => 
  java.security.Security.removeProvider("BC"))
```

Experiment:

```
sbt-classloader-issue$ sbt
> test
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Jul 6, 2017 11:43:53 PM
> test
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jul 6, 2017 11:43:55 PM
```

---

Explanation:

As I can see from your code (published [here](https://github.com/simao/sbt-classloader-issue)):

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider)
```

you're reusing the same `BouncyCastleProvider` provider every-time you run a test, as your `Security.addProvider` works [only first time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Security.html#addProvider(java.security.Provider)). As sbt creates new class-loader for every "test" run, but re-uses the same JVM - `Security` is kind-of JVM-scoped singleton as it was loaded by JVM-bootstrap, so `classOf[java.security.Security].getClassLoader() == null` and sbt cannot reload/reinitialize this class.

And you can easily check that

```
classOf[org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECParameterSpec].getClassLoader()
res30: ClassLoader = URLClassLoader with NativeCopyLoader with RawResources
```

`org.bouncycastle` classes are loaded with custom classloader (from sbt) which changes every-time you run `test`.

So this code:

```
val generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC")
```

gets instance of class loaded from old classloader (the one used for first "test" run) and you're trying to initialize it with spec from new classloader:

```
generator.initialize(ecSpec)
```

That's why you're getting "parameter object not a ECParameterSpec" exception. The reasoning around "net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.EdDSAPublicKey cannot be cast to net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.EdDSAPublicKey" is basically same.